# Is there a way to combine multiple dataframes into one xlsx sheet and multiple dataframes across separate sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Here I have a function for multiple dataframes across separate tabs/sheets

```
# function
def dfs_tabs(df_list, sheet_list, file_name):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')   
    for dataframe, sheet in zip(df_list, sheet_list):
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, startrow=0 , startcol=0)   
    writer.save()

# list of dataframes and sheet names
dfs = [df, df1, df2]
sheets = ['df','df1','df2']    

# run function
dfs_tabs(dfs, sheets, 'multi-test.xlsx')
```

Multiple dataframes into one xlsx sheet

```
# funtion
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')   
    row = 0
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 1
    writer.save()

# list of dataframes
dfs = [df,df1,df2]

# run function
multiple_dfs(dfs, 'Validation', 'test1.xlsx', 1)
```

How can we combine both these two functions?

Need one excel file test1.xlsx with df1,df2,df3 in a sheet name called Validation1 and df4,df5,df6 in a sheet name called Validation2

My attempt:

```
# funtion
def multiple_dfs(df_list1, df_list2, sheet_list, file_name, spaces):   
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')
    row = 0
    for dataframe1, dataframe2, sheet in zip(df_list1, df_list2, sheet_list):
        dataframe1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe1.index) + spaces + 1
        dataframe2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet,startrow=row , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe2.index) + spaces + 1
    writer.save()

# list of dataframes
a_dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
b_dfs = [df4,df5,df6]

sheets = ['sheet1', 'sheet2']
# run function
multiple_dfs(a_dfs, b_dfs, sheets, 'test1.xlsx', 1)
```

Where only sheet1 is created. Can someone let me know where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, spaces):   
    row = 1
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row+1 , startcol=0)   
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 2


# list of dataframes
a_dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
b_dfs = [df4,df5,df6]

# run function
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test1.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
multiple_dfs(a_dfs, "sheet1", 1)
multiple_dfs(b_dfs, "sheet2", 1)
writer.save()
```